Estimator for second order Sobol indices
What is a good estimator for second order Sobol indices? I'm using the estimators from Saltelli et al. for first order and total effect. Can second order indices be estimated from the same sample matrices, i.e. $A,B$ and $A^{(i)}_B$ or is there a need for more?
